# Reverse Procedure for Google Swiffy

Tags: google-swiffy

I am wondering if there is a way to reverse what Swiffy is doing on the SWF. Get the code and make a GIF animation out of it.

Comment: Questions for resources are kind of offtopic here. Why not trying on softwarerecommendations.SE?

Comment: I was asking about how to do that with code, not with a software :)

Answer (score 0):

GIF animation possible do by screenshots